# PHP function not working when I want to execute her in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to include a function from `functions.php` in `accueil.php` but it doesn't work.

See my html code :

```
<div class="milieudepage">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th> Equipe 1 </th>
          <th> Equipe 2 </th>
          <th> Drapeau 1 </th>
          <th> Drapeau 2 </th>
          <th> Score 1 </th>
          <th> Score 2 </th>
          <th> Buvettes </th>
          <th> Volontaires </th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        include("functions.php");
        AfficheMatch();
        ?>
    </table>
  </div>
```

See my php code in `functions.php` :

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

function AfficheMatch()
{
  echo "coucou";
  $req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM Equipe");
  $req->execute();

  while($donnees = $req->fetch())
  {
      echo '<tr><th>'$donnees['pays']'</th><th>'$donnees['drapeau']'</th></tr>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: To clarify, you don't see any of it, not even `coucou`?

Comment: try `functions::AfficheMatch();`

Comment: What do you see if you "view source" the web page?

Comment: Check your web server log.

Comment: functions::AfficheMatch(); not working

Comment: You have errors: `echo '<tr><th>'$donnees['pays']'</th><th>'$donnees['drapeau']'</th></tr>';` You're not concatenating your variables. Should be: `echo '<tr><th>' . $donnees['pays'] . '</th><th>' . $donnees['drapeau'] . '</th></tr>';`

Comment: Check if php is set to display errors or use ini_set('display_errors', 'on').

Comment: _function.php_ or _functions.php_?...

Comment: I have this error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'functions' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site_uefa/accueil.php:52 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site_uefa/accueil.php on line 52

Comment: Yea don't try any of that `functions::` stuff there is no way that would work I have no idea why it was suggested lol

Comment: You need to learn about PHP [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without being able to see the rest of your code, but I'll take a shot:

```
function AfficheMatch()
{
  global $bdd;
  echo "coucou";
  $req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM Equipe");
  $req->execute();

  while($donnees = $req->fetch())
  {
      echo '<tr><th>'.$donnees['pays'].'</th><th>'.$donnees['drapeau'].'</th></tr>';
  }
}
```

Problem 1: There is a syntax error in your original code, you had the variables right up against the strings, like `'<code>'$var`. This will not work, PHP requires you to join strings and/or variables with the `.` operator. So it would be `'<code>'.$var`.

Problem 2: You need to reference the global variable `$bdd` with the `global` keyword inside your function in order to access it.